# use variable in knockout js html

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to use variable in **html** find but in can't find any way to do it. I tried this but not working for me.

```
<!--ko foreach: { data: test(), as: 'method'}-->
       <!--ko var isValid = test_title;
                    /ko !-->
          <tr class="row"><th colspan="4" data-bind="text: isValid"  class="test_title"></th></tr>

<!-- /ko !-->
```

First Experience with KO.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write javascript in a ko comment, but you can write it in the binding value.